# Chrome: Box-shadow not shown on img with background

Tags: google-chrome, background, image, css

I have images on my website with a `background` (loading indicator, but happens with any background) which worked perfectly half a year ago.
But since a few months Chrome doesn't show the box-shadow anymore.

I've set up a fiddle to try to reduce it to the esentials. It only happens to some images (perhaps to do with transparency?) and sometimes it happens only after the image is redrawn (selected, moved). When I remove the background the shadow is visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/PJ7f5/5/

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Consider reporting this bug to Chrome developers. (It's introduced in Chrome 19. Previous Chrome 18 works correctly.)

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=134243

Comment: **+1** Also, for a totally different approach markup wise that may interest you, check out this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LwXPJ/)

Comment: To be sure this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LwXPJ/2/) includes *Text* over the image in case that possibility was not realized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2** See @arttronics comment below.

http://jsfiddle.net/z89x9/37/

```
.img {
    background-color: red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    padding-left: 1px;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
.img:hover {
    margin:2px;
}
​
```

Comment: that works but why? the shadow isn't inset so why is the img over it? In chrome my fiddle shows the shadow until it is selected.  BTW you didn't save your fiddle

Comment: I tried various combos and noticed that as well. I checked the computed style and all seems fine. Can't say I understand it, but adding in padding: -1px works even better. Take a look at the last revision http://jsfiddle.net/z89x9/8/

Comment: it only does because you removed the background ;) it seems to require at least 1px padding

Comment: Take a look now. I've found a solution believe that works it appears.

Comment: Your old sad attempt is +1 for me with added margin. You can have this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z89x9/37/). While `padding` can't have negative value, `margin` can.

Comment: @arttronics create an answer with your solution and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Thomas: With all due respect, I just made a smidgen of improvement for Kirk's answer who has worked hard to create 2 solutions for you. For this reason, please accept his. *P.S. Soon I will be able to edit Answers and contribute that way, as it's not always about rep but making an existing answer better.*

Comment: Thank you Kirk. For clarification, the previous lengthy hack is actually legit but can be looked at it this way: `<div class="shadow"><img src="image.jpg" /></div>`.  That said, the `box-shadow` works correctly when used with a `div tag` since Chrome will respect that `box-model`. Once Chrome fixes the current bug for the `img tag` then this workaround answer is no longer needed. To be sure, Chrome v19 is not respecting `img tag` to be a `box model` element in this particular case.